# How to add a js variable to a form?

Tags: javascript

```
<form action="recapitulatif.html" onsubmit="return isValidForm()" method="get" id="form">

</form>
```

Hi, I have this form which leads to my next page and adds the inputs as parameters.
I'd like to add a js variable (destination) to the parameters. This is assigned by another form in the previous page.

I've tried adding

```
let destination=findGetParameter('destination');
document.getElementById("form").action=("recapitulatif.html?destination="+destination);
```

In the isValidForm() function I use to check for valid input but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution can be to introduce an hidden input field which value you will set from javascript.

This way when you submit the form the value of the destination field will be sent.

```
<form action="recapitulatif.html" method="get" id="form">
    <input id="destination" type="hidden"/>
</form>
```

The advantage of this solution is that you don't have to change the action url or write custom code to handle this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the validation and use the URL API

```
<form action="recapitulatif.html" method="get" id="form">
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  if (!isValid(this)) 
    e.preventDefault();
    return
  }
  const destination=findGetParameter('destination'); // I do not know what findGetParameter does
  const url = new URL(this.action);
  url.searchParams.set("destination",destination)
  this.action=url.toString();
});
```